# Facebook Login: How to combine JavaScript with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

How do I go about combining examples from both

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php and
https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html

The end goal is so that we can use jQuery to sign in, and somehow the following line would still work

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

What I currently notice is that when I sign in with JavaScript, it doesn't set the session with PHP, hence, it is incompatible with PHP based SDK (so $user in this case would still be null)

I am not a big fan of `<a href="$facebook->getLoginUrl()">Login with Facebook</a>`, 
because it causes the browser to load a different page (the facebook login) and then redirects back to the web app. It is far more ideal if I can load up a popup box for user to signin, and then transparently redirects back to my web app. So any suggestions on how I can go about implementing this user experience would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: With latest api you don't need to do anything. Just be sure cookies are on then php SDK will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just use the Facebook login button - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Once the user has used that to login (if they weren't already) and grant access to your app (site), the PHP-SDK should have no trouble using the Facebook session and APIs.

### Update

I just tried this with the new version 3.0 PHP SDK and it is definitely **not** working. Found this on the [developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503)

> If you are using the JavaScript SDK for login in conjunction with the PHP SDK, you will want to wait for the JavaScript SDK upgrade (coming in 4 weeks). Version 3.0.0 of the PHP SDK won’t cooperate with the current JavaScript SDK due to the cookie format changing.

In other words, use the v2 PHP SDK until the JS SDK is updated.

Comment: Actually, I spent quite some time yesterday trying to get your suggestion to work, but it was a no go.
I modified the example from PHP SDK as shown in http://pastebin.com/fy2SRLWM 

And even though I am logged in (fb:login-button would display I am logged in), it does not set the PHP session.

In my app setting, the siteUrl is http://localhost/ for local testing

Comment: @Antony You are totally correct. It seems the PHP SDK no longer has access to the cookie set via the JavaScript SDK. On top of that, I can not logout using the `getLogoutUrl()` method

Comment: Thanks Phil. I came back to this page to comment that I had just read that snippet on the blog. I've been ripping my hair out for the past eight hours trying to figure this out! Oh well...

Comment: @Daniel The problem is all the examples get you to clone / download the master branch. They should have really labelled the v3 branch as beta until the JS SDK caught up

Comment: Thank you Phil! I downgraded to v2 and now it is working!
On the side note, if anyone with v2 running into cert issue due to testing against localhost, see https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/79 for solution.

Comment: That link to the dev blog doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there an updated one?

Comment: @Ben you sure? Opens fine for me

Comment: @Phil.. That's interesting, I was logged in to facebook as a Sandbox'ed App Test user. That causes the blog page to throw a 500..

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if you got this working. The current JS API has a configuration to save the cookie so the server may read it:

```
FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
    cookie : true
});
```

Now, in PHP, you can do the following to use the session from the JS:

```
// Read the cookie created by the JS API
$cookie = preg_replace("/^\"|\"$/i", "", $_COOKIE['fbs_' . FB_APP_ID]);
parse_str($cookie, $data);

// Startup the Facebook object
$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET
));

// Say we are using the token from the JS
$fb->setAccessToken($data['access_token']);

// It should work now
var_dump($fb->getUser());
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: it works for me, but I had to use $_COOKIE['fbm_' . FB_APP_ID ]
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you don't even need to do all that preg_replace stuff anymore. getUser() will owkr outta the box

Comment: In addition to this, the domain on the cookie has to be right - which means, for me, that the fb app settings > App Domains needed to use a naked domain name: example.com not www.example.com. This may only apply to my case where I have multiple subdomains (www, sales.example.com, etc).

Answer (score 1):

it's sound like facebook didn't fix this problem at the right time(as they talk https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503).

this is newest infomation about js sdk
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Answer (score 1):

After long hours of searching, I found this fixed my problem where the PHP SDK did not pick up the Facebook session. Apparently, the Javascript SDK is not setting the session the right way. Add this to your `auth.login` eventlistener:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    FB._oauth = false;
    FB.Cookie.setEnabled(true);
    FB.Auth.setSession(response.authResponse, response.status);
    FB._oauth = true;
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Also, make sure you set the App Domain to match your cookie domain. After fixing these items, it finally worked.

**Edit:**
This morning, everything was working fine. When I was testing some more just now, I found that I had to edit base_facebook.php to make sure the requests to Facebook would not time-out. My guess is that because I am testing on my local machine, the connection would not be fast enough to make it in time. This explains the strange behaviour where sometimes it would and sometimes it would not work.

Alter the connecttimeout in the $CURL_OPTS array on line 128:

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.1',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 4 of the SDK it works automatically with the JavaScript SDK. You just need to use `FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper`:

```
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper(); // Get access token from JS SDK
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// If logged in
if($session) {
    // Get user profile
    try {
        $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 'GET', '/me'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

        print_r($user_profile);

    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

No need to mess around with cookies!